# Js implements input range sliding, when the mouse slides quickly, there will be a freeze

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a custom slider and I'm having the following problem, when my mouse quickly moves horizontally outside the slider's range, beyond the slider's width, the slider's value doesn't ideally go to min or max, instead Is there a pause, is there any way to make it slide smoothly?

**Caton effect**
[image]

```js
 const elWrap = document.getElementById('wrap');
  const elProgress = document.getElementById('progress');

  function onMouseMove(event) {
    const {clientX} = event
    const {left, right} = elWrap.getBoundingClientRect()

    // is the mouse inside the wrap?
    if (clientX < left || clientX > right) return

    // set progress width
    elProgress.style.width = `${(clientX - left) / elWrap.offsetWidth * 100}%`
  }

  // slider mousedown events
  elWrap.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    }, {once: true});
  });
```

```css
.x {
    padding: 128px;
  }

  #wrap {
    border-radius: 999px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 12px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  #progress {
    height: 12px;
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 999px;
    background-color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<div class="x">
  <div id="wrap">
    <div id="progress"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

You are moving your mouse out of the range that the mousemove event is registered outside of the range, but you have this line which just ignores such events:

```
if (clientX < left || clientX > right) return
```

### Solution

Handle out of range events

```
if (clientX < left) {
  elProgress.style.width = `${0}%`;
} else if (clientX > right) {
  elProgress.style.width = `${100}%`;
} else {
  elProgress.style.width = `${((clientX - left) / elWrap.offsetWidth) * 100}%`;
}
```

```js
const elWrap = document.getElementById('wrap');
const elProgress = document.getElementById('progress');

function onMouseMove(event) {
  const {
    clientX
  } = event
  const {
    left,
    right
  } = elWrap.getBoundingClientRect()

  if (clientX < left) {
    elProgress.style.width = `${0}%`
  } else if (clientX > right) {
    elProgress.style.width = `${100}%`
  } else {
    elProgress.style.width = `${(clientX - left) / elWrap.offsetWidth * 100}%`
  }
}

// slider mousedown events
elWrap.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
  }, {
    once: true
  });
});
```

```css
.x {
  padding: 128px;
}

#wrap {
  border-radius: 999px;
  width: 320px;
  height: 12px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#progress {
  height: 12px;
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 999px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="x">
  <div id="wrap">
    <div id="progress"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```